# Received error stating null values cannot be inserted into 'EmailConfirmed' Column in 'AspNetUsers' Table

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I recently added some new columns to the AspNetUsers table in the database (in effort to migrate from Identity 1.0 to 2.0). I set the 'EmailConfirmed' column as nullable however when it came time to run the project and log in, I received an error stating: "**Action: LoginPartial Controller: Account Exception Message: The 'EmailConfirmed' property on 'IdentityUser`4' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Boolean'**."

The error happens inside of the Login method inside of the Account Controller page. Here is some code (it breaks at the line with the user variable):

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenOnAllPosts]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, false);                        

                    return RedirectToAction("HomeIndex", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["ErrorMsg"] = "Incorrect email and/or password. Please try again...";
                }
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form

            return View("LoginPartial", model);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleErrorInfo error = new HandleErrorInfo(e, "Account", "LoginPartial");
            return View("Error", error);
        }
    }
```

Beyond this I am not really sure where to go from here. Does anyone have any clue as to what is causing the error and what I could do to fix it?

P.S. here is a pic of the table in the Database:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you changed the database type, but not the model type.

While your table allows for nulls, your C# class that maps the table does not allow for nulls, being a "bool" instead of a "bool?"

If you are using the Entity Framework, you will have to change your type mapping; otherwise you will find the class that represents the model mapped to your table, and change the type returned by your "UserManager.FindAsync" method

Comment: I got it to work by adding: public bool? EmailConfirmed { get; set; } to IdentityUser class. Thank you for your input.